# Value of textfield with Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase

Tags: zend-framework, phpunit

Could anyone advice on the correct way to retrieve and check the value of a textfield with Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase?  The assert conditions are fine for css selectors, but I cannot see a way of checking that a textfield or other form element is correctly populated? any clues much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

you should validate data entry with [Zend_Validate](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.html) (which is part of the production code). you then would unit test that the value is retrieved correctly after it was stored in the DB.

Comment: Hi Udo, I have some specific login inside the controller to return the data and populate the form, so its more than just using Zend_Validate! as this is actually on the retrieve rather than the save

Comment: maybe adding some sample code will help to better understand the scope